Not getting INFO-level messages from org.geotools.util.logging.Logging
As a Java beginner, I've inherited a custom Geoserver extension, running in a Windows environment. The plugin contains logging code like this:
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.geotools.util.logging.Logging;

[...]

public class ReportBuilder {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logging.getLogger("com.mytld.wps.pins.UploaderProcess");

[...]

    public ReportBuilder(String siteId) {
        LOGGER.info("Overriding props with pins.conf file");
    }
}

Errors result in meaningful info in TOMCAT_INSTALL_DIR/logs/tomcat9-stderr.yyyy.mm.dd.log. But I cannot see any LOGGER.info() output anywhere.
I've read the docs page https://docs.geotools.org/latest/developer/conventions/code/log.html. Trying to apply that info, I find:

I don't think there is a logging.properties file in my source
I've tried compiling with -Dlogging-profile=info-logging but I am still not getting my INFO messages

I've checked ${MAVEN_HOME}/conf/logging/simplelogger.properties, which has:
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=info

What is preventing me from seeing INFO-level output?

Is there any other location I should search for logfiles? I've tried the Tomcat and Geoserver data directories.
Does the Geoserver logging level in global.xml apply to these logs?
Anything else I'm missing?


I think you'll need to add a Logger to the DEFAULT_LOGGING.xml (or whichever level you are using) for your package, something like:
    <Logger name="com.mytld.wps.pins" level="info" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="stdout"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="geoserverlogfile"/>
    </Logger>


That fixed it - thank you so much. For clarification, Ian's changes are to the DEFAULT_LOGGING.xml used by Geoserver, not any file in my source.
